# AspNet Core.EntityFramework 7.0 and SignalR 3.0.0 rc1. Injection

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core

I am trying to use AspNetCore rc1. Also I am using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server: 3.0.0-rc1-final`  and 'EntityFramework.Core: 7.0.0-rc1-final'. I need to update database from my SignalR hub `OnDisconnected` event. For that purpose I have tried to inject my UnitOfWork directly into hubs constructor.

```
public class ReceiptsHub : Hub
{
    public IUnitOfWork<string> UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ReceiptsHub(IUnitOfWork<string> unitOfWork) : base()
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

`IUnitOfWork` has been registered earlier in `Startup.cs`. It is in njectced properly, but the problem is in `DBContext` instance. Implementation of IUnitOfWork requires `DbContext` instance. It is created but its `Model` property throws `'_context.Model' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'`. StackTrace is:

```
in Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.get_ServiceProvider()
in Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.get_Model()
```

Same exception is fired, when I am trying to inject service provider  in hub.

```
    public ReceiptsHub(IServiceProvider provider) : base()
    {
        var context = provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();  
    }
```

Same exception is fired, when I am trying to inject DbContext in hub (instance of context is created, but it is model property throws an exception).

```
    public ReceiptsHub(ApplicationDbContext context) : base()
    {
        Context = context; 
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? Or maybe somebody will help me? and show another way to update database from SignalR hub?

**UPDATE**. My `Startup.cs` code, where I am registring context

```
        // here configured context
        services.AddEntityFramework()
          .AddInMemoryDatabase()
          .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
          {
              options.UseInMemoryDatabase();
          });

        //here configured store and custom manager
        services.AddScoped<IAuthStore<ApplicationUser, ClientApplication>, AuthStore<ApplicationUser, ClientApplication, ApplicationDbContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<AuthManager<ApplicationUser, ClientApplication>>();            
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<string>, UnitOfWork<string, ApplicationDbContext>>();
```

Maybe, problem is in InMemoryDatabase?

Comment: Can you show the code where you register the services in DI (your Startup.cs)? Sounds like a problem with the lifetime of your UnitOfWork .

Comment: Of course. I have updated my question.

Comment: In fact I think I can overcome this. If I will use real database, not in memory, and directly create instance of db context class (i have tried this with in memory database, everything works fine, but database is empty) in hub everything will work fine.  But I do not like such approach

Comment: The way you have your DI set up your IUnitOfWork will get created at the start of each request and disposed at the end. I'm not very experienced with SignalR but your Receipts hub class probably lives across multiple requests (Singleton?) so the IUnitOfWork has a different lifetime and thus gets disposed before your Hub class is done using it.

Comment: I had a breakpoint in my hub class constructor. It is fired for every signalR request.